# Not able to get topic list in gazebo4

Tags: gazebo-4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,
I'm currently working on gazebo4. As like in gazebo 1.9.6 i'm not able to get the topics list using *gztopic list* command in gazebo4.Can anyone tell me right command to get topics list?

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7206/not-able-to-get-topic-list-in-gazebo4/) by [Rahul Sharma](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/924/rahul-sharma/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The command style has changed, type

```
$ gz help
```

to see usage.

To list all topics you should type

```
$ gz topic -l
```

or

```
$ gz topic --list
```

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rahul Sharma](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/924/rahul-sharma/) on 2014-11-22**:
Too late, but thanks for that